# Appending Data from Loop into Dictionary or Series for new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert parsed date times with tz_localize and tz_convert in a loop. What I'd like to do is take each converted timestamp and write it into a dictionary, series, or new dataframe and then join it to the existing dataframe.

Looking at other threads it seems like appending data directly into the dataframe inside the loop isn't the best application of pandas. So after trying append, df.insert, and df.replace, I'm trying to figure out a way to append each converted time into a series or dictionary and then merge it with the original dataframe to convert each timestamp to the location's local time.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp 
from pytz import all_timezones
import datetime

original = pd.read_excel('lab.xls')
data = pd.read_excel('lab.xls')
data = data.drop_duplicates('Site UP')
data = data.drop(data[data.Duration == 0].index)
data.to_excel('no duplicates no zeroes.xls', 'a')
holder = ''

local_time = pd.Series([])
def conversion_function():
    data = pd.read_excel('no duplicates no zeroes.xls')
    for Time_Zone, datetime in zip(data["Time_Zone"], data["Site DOWN"]):
        if Time_Zone == "Atlantic":
            raw_time_2 = Timestamp(datetime)
            loc_raw_time_2 = raw_time_2.tz_localize("US/Pacific")
            print(loc_raw_time_2)
            atlantic_time = loc_raw_time_2.tz_convert('Canada/Atlantic')
            print('Adjusted time is:', atlantic_time)
        elif Time_Zone == 'Central':
            raw_time_3 = Timestamp(datetime)
            loc_raw_time_3 = raw_time_3.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
            print(loc_raw_time_3)
            central_time = loc_raw_time_3.tz_convert('US/Central')
            print('Adjusted time is:', central_time)
        elif Time_Zone == "Eastern":
            raw_time_1 = Timestamp(datetime)
            loc_raw_time_1 = raw_time_1.tz_localize("US/Pacific")
            print(loc_raw_time_1)
            eastern_time = loc_raw_time_1.tz_convert("US/Eastern")
            print('Adjusted time is:', eastern_time)
        elif Time_Zone == 'Mountain':
            raw_time_4 = Timestamp(datetime)
            loc_raw_time_4 = raw_time_4.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
            print(loc_raw_time_4)
            mountain_time = loc_raw_time_4.tz_convert('US/Mountain')
            print('Adjusted time is:', mountain_time)
    data['Local Time'] = data[['Time Zone', 'Site Down']].apply(conversion_function, axis=1) 

data.insert(7, 'Local Time', holder, True)
#data.to_excel('delete.xls', 'a')
```

Here's an example dataframe:

```
Region  Time_Zone   Site DOWN       Site UP         Duration
US      Mountain    07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:23  4
Canada  Central     07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:23  4
US      Eastern     07/21/19 22:50  07/21/19 22:52  2
US      Eastern     07/16/19 11:26  07/16/19 11:29  3
US      Pacific     07/25/19 16:47  07/25/19 16:50  3
US      Pacific     07/22/19 13:13  07/22/19 13:15  2
US      Pacific     07/22/19 01:20  07/22/19 01:22  2
US      Central     06/30/19 11:56  06/30/19 11:58  2
US      Mountain    07/29/19 03:14  07/29/19 03:16  2
US      Mountain    07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:23  4
Canada  Atlantic    07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:21  2
Canada  Eastern     07/03/19 06:51  07/03/19 11:34  283
US      Eastern     07/21/19 16:51  07/21/19 16:53  2
US      Eastern     07/21/19 13:43  07/21/19 16:31  168
Canada  Atlantic    07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:21  2
US      Mountain    07/18/19 01:30  07/18/19 01:58  28
US      Central     07/22/19 01:20  07/22/19 01:22  2
Canada  Central     07/17/19 22:17  07/17/19 22:21  4
Canada  Central     07/15/19 06:14  07/15/19 08:42  148
Canada  Mountain    07/22/19 01:19  07/22/19 01:23  4
Canada  Mountain    07/22/19 01:18  07/22/19 01:21  3
Canada  Central     07/22/19 01:20  07/22/19 01:22  2
Canada  Central     07/17/19 09:26  07/17/19 09:28  2
Canada  Atlantic    07/30/19 18:18  07/31/19 04:44  626
Canada  Atlantic    07/29/19 21:20  07/29/19 21:22  2
Canada  Atlantic    07/25/19 03:41  07/25/19 03:43  2
Canada  Atlantic    07/22/19 01:20  07/22/19 01:23  3
Canada  Atlantic    07/21/19 22:50  07/21/19 22:50  0
Canada  Eastern     07/24/19 01:57  07/24/19 03:55  118
```

Comment: @Trenton_M thanks for your feedback and patience. I'm still relatively new to python so I tried making the changes you've suggested but am getting a dtype='object' error. Do I have to change the dtype output from the conversion_function() ?

Comment: I'd also recommend upgrading to python3.7.  You can use the anaconda distribution.   [Python 2.7 is end of life](https://pythonclock.org/)

Comment: @Trenton_M I added some raw data from the dataframe when it's read from read_excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('lab.csv')

data['Site DOWN'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Site DOWN'])
data['Site UP'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Site UP'])
```

#### `DataFrame`:

[image]

### Conversion Function Updated:

```py
def conversion_function(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Timestamp:  # type hints won't work for python 2.7

    zones = {'Atlantic': 'Canada/Atlantic',
             'Central': 'US/Central',
             'Eastern': "US/Eastern",
             'Mountain': 'US/Mountain',
             'Pacific': 'US/Pacific'}

    raw_time = pd.Timestamp(x[1])
    loc_raw_time = raw_time.tz_localize("US/Pacific")
    return loc_raw_time.tz_convert(zones[x[0]])
```

#### Call function:

```
data['Adjusted_Time'] = data[['Time_Zone', 'Site DOWN']].apply(conversion_function, axis=1)
```

#### Updated `DataFrame`:

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, thank you so much for all your patience, continued help and thorough explanations! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @cgarrido Note the update to `conversion_function`.  `Adjusted_Time` for `Pacific` is now in the same format as all other time-zones.